# unknown error: call function result missing 'value' for Selenium Send Keys even after chromedriver upgrade

Tags: python-2.7, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am getting the below error while sending keys.

Result Message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.146)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

I have updated the chrome driver to 2.36 but still my code search for 2.33?

Any idea ?

Comment: Same problem here since yesterday. In my case, I think the problem is a combination of headless chrome v65 + selenium driver v2.34 (changelog says it's compatible with chrome v61-63)

Answer (score 118):

I've gotten the same error, please download the last ChromeDriver version and/or update chrome browser version and it will be working fine :)

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.36/

Comment: I have downloaded it and referred as Nuget and removed all references to 2.33 but still it connects to old 2.33 one ?

Comment: I downloaded newest chromedriver 2.36 and it still does not work with Chrome Version 65.0.3325.146 (Official Build) (64-bit)
At least on Mac OS :(

Comment: Me too. I downloaded the latest version and it still didn't work. my script had been working for quite some time until it suddenly hit this issue.

Comment: Oh, apologises, I actually configured my path wrongly, and after I linked it to the new chromedriver, my script actually works now. I am using a windows machine by the way.

Comment: If you're using https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper gem, then run in console `chromedriver-update 2.36`

Comment: I'm using protractor with webdriver-manager and also had to update the config.json file in the protractor folder to point at the new version. See my answer below for the exact steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49288152/284704.

Comment: Update the chromedriver version and set Chromedriver.set_version "latest chromedriver version" in your spec_helper.rb, It dependents on gem chromedriver-helper.

Comment: If you use Homebrew, you can execute `brew upgrade chromedriver`

Answer (score 23):

After updating the Google Chrome browser to *Version 65.0.3325.146 (Official Build) (64-bit)*, I'm also encountered with the same error 
 while sending values to the input field, here's the error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
```

*using Chromedriver 2.32 and Google Chrome 65.0*

As I did some research on the same, I found a recent [commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/45c0029def3706a9b37b9fc5b0e83386749a10c1) on Google chrome v65 changelogs which help me to resolve the issue.

**Solution:**

- Update Google Chrome to latest stable version (in my case it's v65 on 9/mar/2018)
- Download and configure latest chromedriver (v2.36).
  For configuring chromedriver (on Ubuntu) follow these steps...

  1. Extract the downloaded zip file.
  2. Copy the extracted chromedriver file to **/usr/local/bin** or to the location where you usually store the executable binaries.
  3. Add the same path (where you place the chromedriver file) to environment variable PATH as

> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin

4. For testing the installation, restart the terminal and type this command

> chromedriver --version

it would show the version of chromedriver that you just installed.

**Note:**  If the chromedriver already installed and configured then just replace the existing driver file and If you don't know where the Chromedriver binaries already stored then try to find the file using following command

```
 sudo find -H / -type f -iname chromedriver
```

Answer (score 13):

It is because of the update of chrome browser version from 64.xx to 65.xx

Now you have 2 options to run your tests successfully.

1. Downgrade your chrome browser to previous version and with the old chromedriver which you have now.
2. Upgrade your Chromedriver to 2.36 version with the updated Chrome browser.

   visit https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.36 and download the new chromedriver.

Option 2 is better.

Comment: I am in the following environment: Ubuntu 16.04, GoogleChrome 65.0.3325.146, ChromeDriver 2.36.540471. And i still get the exact error above. What do I need to change? The error, however says I am using chromedriver version 2.33.506092...

Comment: You need to mention the exact path of latest chromedriver which you have updated not a old one. or Replace the old chromedriver with new one. Just check it.

Comment: If anybody encounter this error in Visual studio, upgrade to chrome web driver Nuget package to 2.37(at time of writing) will solve this error.

Answer (score 12):

Replace your ChromeDriver.exe with latest version.. Same can be  downloaded from Google easily.

Also its better to get it done automatically by using webDriver manager as explained below -
1. Add Mvn dependency to your project POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>${webdrivermanager.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

2. Now in your Browser instantiation class **instead of using traditional way** to create driver i.e. by using System.setProperty(See belwo)...

   > System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");

**Use below approach:**

> WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
>   webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

And that's all, you are done!

Use below links for your reference-
[What is Browser Binary Manager how to use it for Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53276021/what-is-browser-binary-manager-how-to-use-it-for-selenium)

or chkout git project for same-
https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager#webdrivermanager-as-java-dependency

Comment: This worked for me - the downloads for 2.37 can be found here: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.37/

Comment: Yeah and now the latest one is- ChromeDriver 2.38 -http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Answer (score 10):

Need to update chromedriver :
In console, run:  `chromedriver-update 2.36`

Answer (score 10):

The error says it all :

```
System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.146)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120
```

The error clearly complains about **InvalidOperationException**

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.33*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.33*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v60-62**

- You are using *chrome=65.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.37*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v64-66**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is unknown to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver* version (*v2.33*) and the *Chrome Browser* version (*v65.0*)

### Solution

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  [**ChromeDriver v2.37**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version in between ***Chrome v64.x-66.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.37 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Browser/Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Browser/Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are on Mac:

```
brew upgrade selenium-server-standalone
brew upgrade chromedriver
```

if the above two are not installed:

```
brew install selenium-server-standalone
brew install chromedriver
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm running Protractor and have encountered the same issue.

The solution in my case was rather simple.

`$ npm update protractor -g`

`$ webdriver-manager update`

Comment: If you're using `gulp-protractor` plugin, make sure to update it as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on the latest stable Google Chrome (e.g. 67) I recommend to:

```
brew uninstall chromedriver
brew tap homebrew/cask
brew cask install chromedriver
```

These set of commands will uninstall your current chromedriver, check for updates and install the latest found (e.g. 2.40).

Answer (score 1):

```
Use xpaths instead of class names to locate elements
```

After updating chrome and its drivers it didn't helped me at all!!
I don't know how much it makes sense but it worked for me when i replaced class name with xpath. This is the xpath , i used to automate sending whatsapp message using python.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div')
```

previously i Was Using

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('Some class Name Here')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Protractor (webdriver-manager) with Selenium in a Windows environment, and I had to do the following:

1. `webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome="2.36"` (This downloaded the new Chromedriver to the right path but didn't enable it in protractor.)
2. Edit `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\config.json` and changed the `chromedriver` value from `2.32` to `2.36`.
3. Delete my old `chromedriver_2.32.exe` from `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\selenium` for good measure (not sure if that was required.)

**Or:**

When another Chromedriver update became needed, I was no longer able to update this way. A configuration setting still expected the old path and filename, and I couldn't figure out where to change that setting. So I just renamed the latest chromedriver to "chromedriver.exe" and stuck it in C:\Windows\system32 (which is always referenced by PATH). Crude, but effective.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the team I'm on points selenium to a specific chromedriver file we had. In order to get Selenium to use the updated chromedriver, I first installed it with brew and then created a symbolic link to point where Selenium looks for it:

```
brew install chromedriver
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/chromedriver/2.36/bin/chromedriver /path/where/selenium/expects/chromedriver
```

Answer (score 0):

On the chance this might be helpful to someone I needed an additional step:

I am on MacOS X.  I did

```
brew upgrade chromedriver
bundle exec chromedriver-upgrade
```

I have the chromedriver-helper gem installed, but it is stashed and requires the "bundle exec" prefix or the shell can't find the command.

The above fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, the latest chromedriver did the trick for me. In case you downloaded the driver manually and want to tell appium to use the new chromedriver you can do so by this command:

`appium --chromedriver-executable /path/to/driver/chromedriver ....`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `gulp-protractor` plugin, make sure to update it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still on this, but I was receiving a similar error. I had the latest version of chromedriver in my PATH and Google Chrome was updated. I run Python 3.6 on windows 10 x64 bit. What I was getting trying to select a value from a dropdown menu on a webpage. The weird thing was, it would select the dropdown value correctly and the page would be updated nicely, but I'd receive that stupid error anyway and my script would freeze. So I just made an exception error handler for it, because like I said it selected the dropdown value correctly, so I just wanted to bypass that dumb error message:

```
# select by value
try:
    select.select_by_value('100')
except:
    pass
```

hopefully someone finds this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of mismatch in chromedriver and chrome browser version.
Below link specifies the versions of chromedriver supporting the chrome browser's version.

http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads