# Nightwatch expected visible but got not visible

Tags: nightwatch.js, browser-automation

I have been setting up some tests with Nightwatch. I ran the following basic test on their website.

```
module.exports = {
    'Search on google': (browser) => {
        browser
            .url('http://www.google.com')
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
            .setValue('input[type=text]', 'nightwatch')
            .waitForElementVisible('button[name=btnG]', 1000)
            .click('button[name=btnG]')
            .pause(1000)
            .assert.containsText('#main', 'Night Watch')
            .end()
    },
    after: (browser) => {
        browser.end()
    } 
};
```

And got the following error:

`Timed out while waiting for element <button[name=btnG]> to be visible for 1000 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: "not visible"`

My first attempt at correcting was to change `.waitForElementVisible('button[name=btnG]', 1000)` to 10000 but still ended up getting `Timed out while waiting for element <button[name=btnG]> to be visible for 10000 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: "not visible"`.

Inspecting the google search button showed me that the button name was actually btnK so I tested that but it didn't work either returning `expected "visible" but got: "not found"`.

Very stumped and not sure where to go from here. Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you're running this on Chrome 65? A recent change essentially causes `setValue` to error out. Your Nightwatch test would then fail on the next step. The best solution is to update your Chromedriver to 2.36.

Please see the answers here: [unknown error: call function result missing 'value' for Selenium Send Keys even after chromedriver upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162667/unknown-error-call-function-result-missing-value-for-selenium-send-keys-even)

Comment: Wow, this actually helped out a lot. I wasn't able to find this in my search earlier but thank you so much. It worked out!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I had installed ChromeDriver from NPM it was v2.45.*. My Chrome version was v69*. When I downloaded the chrome driver from this link- https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.36/ and updated my nightwatch.json to point to this downloaded chrome driver version using `server_path`. This solved the issue.