# Python Selenium driver.execute_script WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is actually for the thread on [unknown error: call function result missing 'value' for Selenium Send Keys even after chromedriver upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162667/unknown-error-call-function-result-missing-value-for-selenium-send-keys-even)
but I guess my reputation isn't high enough to participate(lame).

I got the error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.162)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506106 
  platform=Mac OS X 10.13.3 x86_64)
```

when running this line:

```
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, %s)' % scroll_to)
```

I updated and everything else but that error still popped up, however the code actually executed before raising the error, so simply passing the exception allowed me to accomplish my goal, kinda sloppy so it'd be cool if I could make the error go away for real, but this is working for now:

```
driver.get('https://www.azcentral.com/search/trump/')
page_height = int(driver.get_window_size()['height'])
scroll_to = 0
start_time = time.time()
wait = 90

while True:

    scroll_to += page_height

    try:

        driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, %s)' % scroll_to)

    except:

        time.sleep(1)
        pass

    end_time = time.time()
    uptime = timedelta(seconds=int(end_time - start_time))

    if uptime > timedelta(seconds=wait):

        break
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says it all :

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.162)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506106
```

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.33*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.33*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v60-62**

- You are using *chrome=65.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.37*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v64-66**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is unknown to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver* version (*v2.33*) and the *Chrome Browser* version (*v65.0*)

### Solution

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.37**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version in between ***Chrome v64.x-66.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.37 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use such code for this:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: running that line produces the same error - "WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'."