# Selenium - Error while sending keys

Tags: java, windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

While trying to send keys I get this exception.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 72 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'asih', ip: '10.30.100.142', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_20'
```

Driver

Using :

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.37/

Getting :

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 72 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'asih', ip: '10.30.100.142', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_20'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41), userDataDir=C:\Users\asih\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir4940_12561}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=65.0.3325.181, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: e40878bb2160b9b28b332daf82035d56
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:122)
    at com.ever_complient.page_objects.LoginPage$Activate.login(LoginPage.java:52)
    at com.ever_complient.building_blocks.ui_specific.GeneralUIService$Activate.login(GeneralUIService.java:72)
    at com.ever_complient.EverComplientTest.scanSummaryTest(EverComplientTest.java:296)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Did you check this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609069/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-call-function-result-miss

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Selenium driver.execute\_script WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49436756/python-selenium-driver-execute-script-webdriverexception-message-unknown-error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609069/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-call-function-result-miss)

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609069/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-call-function-result-miss

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using chrome browser version 64+ and your chrome driver is not latest.

Please take latest version of chrome driver from here : https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.37/

After following above your send key should work.