# ERROR org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value' using Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

**Selenium web driver error log**:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: call function 
>       result missing 'value'

```
(Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:03.216Z'
System info: host: 'IT-DEVESHBD', ip: '172.16.64.243', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_20'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.30.477700 (0057494ad87321..., userDataDir: C:\Users\DEVESH~1\AppData\L...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 68.0.3440.106, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 3f5e94036132dc66e554617f29ece913
```

Any input on this error would be highly appreciated

Comment: I used solution from below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162667/unknown-error-call-function-result-missing-value-for-selenium-send-keys-even but problem is not resolved

Comment: Yes you changed the chromedriver but I think you forgot to change the path in you code so the error is showing  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 ) that means still pointing to the older version of the chromedriver. please change it wherever you mentioned the path of the chrome driver.