# Add eMail and Password in login script with robotframework

Tags: error-handling, robotframework, login-script

I created this script in RobotFram

```html
*** Settings ***
Documentation               This is a basic test for Linkedin Login
Library                     Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${Browser}          chrome
${SiteUrl}          https://www.linkedin.com/
${username}         xpath=//*[@id="login-email"]
${psw}              xpath=//*[@id="login-password"]
${sigin}            xpath=//*[@id="login-submit"]


*** Test Cases ***
Login Page

    open browser    ${SiteUrl}    ${Browser}

    Input Text      ${username} nouser@test.com
    sleep           30 sec
    Input Text      ${psw} nopsw

    click button    ${sigin}

    close browser
```

I have a problem when I insert the mail and password in the 'eMail' and 'password' fields.

The report gives me this error:

```
KEYWORD Selenium2Library . Input Text ${username} nouser@test.com
```

Documentation:
Types the given `text` into text field identified by `locator`.

> Start / End / Elapsed:    20190311 21:59:48.408 / 20190311 21:59:48.408 /
>   00:00:00.000 21:59:48.408 FAIL    Keyword 'Selenium2Library.Input Text'
>   expected 2 arguments, got 1.

Answer (score 4):

The error explains itself:

> FAIL Keyword 'Selenium2Library.Input Text' expected 2 arguments, got 1.

The command is expecting two arguments but it only got one, the reason is that you're using only one space between the args, you need at least two or more spaces between them.
So this:

```
Input Text      ${username} nouser@test.com
```

Should be this:

```
Input Text      ${username}     nouser@test.com
```

Just like:     `open browser    ${SiteUrl}    ${Browser}`

Comment: Thanks for replay. So do you think that it is only a question of space between the arguments?

Comment: Yes, because if you have only one space, the command will expect the `${username} nouser@test.com` as one argument, and will throw an error asking for the second one

Comment: Right! Now I can see this kind of info:
22:35:32.434 INFO Typing text 'nouser@test.com' into text field 'xpath=//*[@id="login-email"]' 
22:35:33.032 FAIL WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.121)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.3 x86_64)

Comment: @Ngiulino this is a Selenium related issue, you'll have to download the latest chrome driver to fix it, please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162667/unknown-error-call-function-result-missing-value-for-selenium-send-keys-even