# WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value' -- after running send_keys and updating Chromedriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I've used Selenium a handful of times and never had any problems though admittedly it has been a little over a year since I last tested it.

I tried running the following:

```
def time_sleep(sec, times_random):
    seconds = sec + (random.random() * times_random)
    return time.sleep(seconds)

def navigate_website(website_name):
    browser.get(website_name)
    time_sleep(1, 3)
    
def fill_field(x_path, text):
    element = browser.find_element_by_xpath(x_path)
    time_sleep(1, 1)
    element.send_keys(text)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    navigate_website('https://www.prc.gov/dockets/search')
    time_sleep(1, 3)
    fill_field('//*[@id="TitleContains"]', 'some text')
```

When I got the subsequent error after running `send_keys()`:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.111)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426935 (820a95b0b81d33e42712f9198c215f703412e1a1),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.6 x86_64)
```

I downloaded the version of chromedriver for Chrome 86.x and tried updating Chrome to the latest version (it says 86.x is up-to-date). Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49528998/1387701 might help.

Comment: @DMart I've looked at that. It basically just tells me to update Chrome or the Webdriver, which I believe I've done but it doesn't hurt to check again.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution was fairly easy. I just needed to move the updated `chromedriver` to the appropriate path. Originally I thought it was enough to have the driver in my project path but `selenium` kept calling the version found in `/usr/local/bin`.

Solution:

1. Download [Chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and unzip file.
2. Open terminal and type `mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin`